# Array_unique SORT_REGULAR flag

Tags: php

```
$array = array(1, '1a', '1');
var_export(array_unique($array, SORT_REGULAR));
```

- The result: array ( 0 => 1, 2 => '1')
- In the PHP manual: SORT_REGULAR - compare items normally (don't change types).

What is the logic behind this ? Why or how is '1a' excluded ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This happens because `array_unique` works by *[first sorting the values as strings](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/ext/standard/array.c#2787)*, then [iterating](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/ext/standard/array.c#2815) over the sorted array and for each value excluding from the result *all successive values that compare equal to it*.

The comparison function for "comparing equal" above is chosen according to the second parameter, which for `SORT_REGULAR` is the same as an equality check with `==`.

This behavior gives rise to a whole lot of gotchas. Since the sort is quicksort, it's  unstable. Therefore sorting an array that contains both `1` and `'1'` gives no guarantee which one will end up being first in the result. This means that `array_unique` may appear to arbitrarily "prefer" `1` in some cases and `'1'` in others.

However the madness continues: consider that if the sort produces `[1, '1', '1a']` then `'1a'` will *not* be included in the result (it compares equal to `1`) while if the sort produces `['1', 1, '1a']` then it *will* be included (it does not compare equal to the string `'1'`)!

Comment: Does this iteration only happen once? Because then we should get duplicate values if another `1` is included after `5`

Comment: @OneTrickPony: I didn't explicitly mention that the array is sorted first (the documentation does). But on second thought it's quite important because the sort is not stable (quicksort), so let me expand the answer a bit.

Comment: @OneTrickPony: Actually it works a bit different than what I believed -- and you will probably not be surprised to know that the behavior cannot be predicted in cases such as this because, well, PHP.

Comment: Indeed it's very unpredictable, I see that `array(1, '1a', '1', 4, 1)` returns `(1, 4)`. So SORT_REGULAR is useless :)

Comment: @OneTrickPony: And best of all: it could also **legitimately** return `['1', 4]` or `['1', '1a', 4]`!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get a little more technical, you can see the source.

The `PHP_SORT_REGULAR` flag simply tells `array_unique` to fall back to the standard comparison operator (`==`).

You can see this in the source for [`array_unique`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/array.c#L2777) which uses [`php_set_compare_func`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/array.c#L144):

```
static void php_set_compare_func(int sort_type TSRMLS_DC) /* {{{ */
{
switch (sort_type & ~PHP_SORT_FLAG_CASE) {
...
    case PHP_SORT_REGULAR:
    default:
        ARRAYG(compare_func) = compare_function;
        break;
}
```

Where `compare_func` is just the [standard comparison function](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/a744390c503645d0326a2aff26c986f85ffc3a01/Zend/zend_operators.c#L1457).

It's probably a documentation bug more than anything else. The comment in the documentation is a bit misleading:

> ...equal if and only if (string) $elem1 === (string) $elem2

If both values are cast to strings, then the `===` is unnecessary, but it leads to the assumption that `SORT_REGULAR` does a type comparison.